# Set Base URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a clients area so my customers can review their site during development. I want to set it up so the URL is `http://clients.mydomain.com/clientname/`

Is there a way in the .htaccess file to set that as the base URL? I'm using the leading / format for my URLs in the page (ie /about/ or /css/), which will is fine locally & when I deploy to production, but doesn't work in the scenario outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use relative links in your HTML, it's unreliable to try to track the referer and rewrite every subsequent request to shove the /clientname/ back in as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a subdomain for each customer, and develop sites there, you don't have to change the base URL. This will prevent other htaccess rules to break also when deploying to the live server...
So use:
http://clientname.mydomain.com